# Google sheets: Return value of first non-empty cell above found value

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I need a formula that searches for the data in specific cells of column `Sheet2!c:c`. it should search the text in `Sheet1!B:B` for the data but return the value of the first non-empty cell above it.

I've tried the following formulas, but it seems to only return the cell directly above the found data rather than the first non-empty cell above...

`=INDEX(Sheet1!B$1:B$1200, MAX(IF(Sheet1!B$1:B$1200=Sheet2!C1, ROW(Sheet1!B$1:B$1200), 0))-1)`

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR( INDEX(Sheet1!B$1:B$1200, MATCH(C1:C, Sheet1!B$1:B$1200, 0) - 1), "" ))`

rockinfreakshow suggested I add this sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RokDxvjoCkDUHZ_MsjpI2uHgG3djqohS4aUJaqZP6oo/edit#gid=1765762558

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & work out a solution. You may also use the [anonymous blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by docs community forum for ease of sharing.

Comment: Here you go...https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RokDxvjoCkDUHZ_MsjpI2uHgG3djqohS4aUJaqZP6oo/edit#gid=1765762558

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=map(C2:C,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(chooserows(tocol(Sheet1!B1:index(Sheet1!B:B,xmatch(Σ,Sheet1!B:B)-1),1),-1)))))
```

*Your other ideal scenario in Column_E(`based on boldness of font`) may be possible via `[google-apps-script]` if someone can pitch in*

[image]

Comment: that's a fancy code, and it seems to be working! thanks so much!